# Return sub list of elements based on matching sub strings from another list

Tags: python, list

I want to filter a list of string based on another list of sub strings.

```
main_list=['London','England','Japan','China','Netherland']
sub_list=['don','land']
```

I want my result to be:-

```
['London','England','Netherland']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, one option is to use `any` in a list comprehension to check if a sub-string in `sub_list` exists in a string in `main_list` to filter the relevant strings:

```py
out = [place for place in main_list if any(w in place for w in sub_list)]
```

Output:

```py
['London', 'England', 'Netherland']
```